# Laravel 5.5 - Model fields

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

In the Laravel 5.5 documentation it is explained that in order to define the database fields it is necessary to write something like this in the model:

```
protected $fillable = [
     'name', 'email', 'password', 'birth_date'
];
```

How can I specify the type of field (boolean, datetime, etc)?

Comment: You don’t. The `$fillable` array is for defining which fields are _mass-assignable_, not what fields the corresponding database table has. For creating the database tables, check out [migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the `$fillable` array you need to define the accessible fields from ur database with ur model, read this in the laravel doc [fillable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#mass-assignment).

to specify the type of field u can use the `$casts`  array inside ur model to cast the data from ur database inside the model with a specific type for that read this in the laravel doc [casts](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting)